# Mapping EFcomplex Entities into WCF DataContracts using AutoMapper

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4, automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper and i have the following manual mapping in CustomerService in Service Layer in my application, where i tried to find out the equivalent AutoMapper mapping code but i couldn't due to nested and complex objects and collections, so please help me to resolve this issue

here the code from CustomerService : Service.Customer is the DataContract and Data.Customer is the Entity

```
public Service.Customer GetCustomer(string customerID)
    {
        Data.Customer customer
            = _northwindEntities
                .Customers.Single(
                    c => c.CustomerID == customerID);
        return new Service.Customer
                   {
                       CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
                       CompanyName = customer.CompanyName,
                       ContactName = customer.ContactName,
                       Address = customer.Address,
                       City = customer.City,
                       Country = customer.Country,
                       Region = customer.Region,
                       PostalCode = customer.PostalCode,
                       Phone = customer.Phone,
                       Orders 
                        = GetOrders(customer.Orders)
                   };
    }
```

Service.Order is the DataContract and Data.Order is the Entity ...

```
private static IEnumerable<Service.Order> GetOrders(
        IEnumerable<Data.Order> order)
    {
        return order.Select(o => new Service.Order
            {
                OrderID = o.OrderID,
                OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                OrderDetails = GetOrderDetails(o),
                Freight = o.Freight,
                ShippedDate = o.ShippedDate
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Service.OrderDetail is the DataContract and Data.Order is the Entity ...

```
private static IEnumerable<Service.OrderDetail> GetOrderDetails(
        Data.Order order)
    {

        return order.Order_Details.Select(
            o => new Service.OrderDetail
            {
                Product 
                    = new Service.Product
                    {
                        ProductID 
                            = o.Product.ProductID,
                        ProductName 
                            = o.Product.ProductName
                    },
                Quantity = o.Quantity,
                UnitPrice = o.UnitPrice
            }).ToList();
    }
```

So OrderDetails are nested inside Oreders and Orders are nested inside Customer ...How to reflect this hierarchy using AutoMapper
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to define mappings for the Parent class and all the nested classes, you can then customize them as per your requirements

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Customer, Service.Customer>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Order, Service.Order>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<Data.OrderDetails, Service.OrderDetails>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Product, Service.Product>();
```

Have a look at this

http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nested%20Mappings

Comment: my scenario is more complex because it is multiple levels of nested collections not just simple nesting as you indicate.Also how to use the Entity Framework  Database context to get the data

Comment: It is as simple as @Tejal indicates. That's the whole point of Automapper, to make mapping simple. You map each level of the hierarchy with one line of code.Your code indicates 4 layer hierarchy. Also, asking how to get data with Entity Framework. Really? Do you think it can be answered in a few lines?